# Why is the Page Number menu item greyed out in Pages '09?

Tags: pages, iwork

I want to insert a page number in my iWork document. I clicked on Insert and the Page Number title is grayed out.

How can I get the page number feature to activate? I used to insert it in other documents with no problem.

[image]

Comment: Is a cell selected ?

Comment: If you post the URL of the image as a plain link (you may have to directly upload it at imgur.com) then one of us with sufficient reputation will edit it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's greyed out because it needs somewhere to insert the page number. You have no insertion point active in the document to insert the page number. Click in the body of the document in a text box or other text entry area, then try selecting Insert → Page Number.